# setting breaks and labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, choroplethr

I have put together the Shiny app (below), showing a choropleth, which looks good except for the scientific notation on the legend.

I would like the values to read: '$5,000,000', and '$4,000,000', etc, etc.

[image]

The code boils down to

```
g <-choroplethr(DF, lod="state", num_buckets = 1)
g <- g + scale_fill_gradient(high = "springgreen4", low= "grey90", name="Sum")
```

I attempted this:

```
g <- q + scale_fill_gradient(high = "springgreen4", low= "grey90", name="Sum", labels = c("5,000,000", "4,000,000", "3,000,000", "2,000,000", "1,000,000"))
```

But I got the error, **Breaks and labels are different lengths**

I'm not sure how I can specify breaks on the x axis when I'm dealing with a map?  How can I create breaks that work with the labels I want to include?  Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are adding argument `labels=` to `scale_fill_gradient()` then you should also add argument `breaks=` that is the same length as your labels.

```
+ scale_fill_gradient(high = "springgreen4", low= "grey90", name="Sum", 
          labels = c("5,000,000", "4,000,000", "3,000,000", "2,000,000", "1,000,000"),
           breaks = c(5000000, 4000000, 3000000, 2000000, 1000000))
```

In this case a better solution would be to just use the `dollar` format from the `scales` library. That will automatically add dollar signs and commas to the labels.

```
library(scales)
+ scale_fill_gradient(labels=dollar)
```

Comment: in addition to above for dollar format, this could work `labels = paste0("$",c("5,000,000", "4,000,000", "3,000,000", "2,000,000", "1,000,000"))`,